# Variance of $\int_0^1X(t)dt$

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, variance

Let $X(t)$ be a stationary random variable with expected value $E[X(t)] = m$ and  covariance function $r_X(\tau) = 2e^{-|\tau|}$.

I'm asked to calculate the variance of $\int_0^1X(t)dt$, 
$$V[\int_0^1X(t)dt].$$ 
I've tried using the formula 
$$C[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$
but I can't figure out $$E[\int_0^1X(t)dt\cdot\int_0^1X(t)dt].$$
How do I do it? Note; all the information given may not be necessary.

The answer is supposedly $4e^{-1}.$

Comment: Write your product of integrals as a 2-d integral, and put the $E$ under the integration sign.

Answer (score 1):

Variance$=E(\int_0^1(X(t)-m)dt)^2)={\int_0^1\int_0^1E(X(t)-m)(X(s)-m))dtds}$

$=\int_0^1\int_0^12e^{-|t-s|}dtds=I$.  This integral is a bit messy. $I=2\int_0^1(e^{-s}\int_0^s e^tdt+e^s\int_s^1e^{-t}dt)ds=\frac{4}{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

As kimchi lover says,
\begin{align}
E\int_0^1\int_0^1(X_t-m)(X_s-m)dsdt 
& = 
2E\int_0^1\int_0^t(X_t-m)(X_s-m)dsdt\\
& =
2\int_0^1\int_0^t2e^{-(t-s)}dsdt\\
& = 4e^{-1}.
\end{align}